# How to create a folder in filezilla after root directory using vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, directory

I need to create a folder after root directory in filezill.
I have used the code to create folder in exe deployed folder.Its working fine in local system.But if i put the same code in azure the directory is taking some path like

```
C:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\Factnni\xumdkbqb.aem\Output_Files\infantile_adv
```

instated of `/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/triggered/factnni`

How to create in this folder?

```
 Dim executablepath As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Console.WriteLine(executablepath)
    outputPath = Path.Combine(executablepath, "Output_Files", "infantile_adv")
    Console.WriteLine(outputPath)
    If Not Directory.Exists(outputPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath)
    End If
```

Comment: Filezilla is sftp client, not a file location. Are you asking how to deploy your code to a server?